# websocket in the wild vs dev machine

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, iis, websocket, reverse-proxy

I'm experiencing different behaviors with my websocket ping/pong between my development environement and my real deployment.

When I started this project, I took some time to test the websocket ping/pong feature to delegate the keepalive/connection check to the websocket stack. My primary goal is to know if the remote client is disconnected ASAP. So I added a server side websocket keepalive (let's say 20sec).

**On my dev machine**, I had something like:

```
[device] <==> [switch] <==> [asp.net core app(kestrel)]
```

In that case everything is fine: when I disconnect the websocket client device, after the 20sec (ok, a bit more sometimes) I get a notification that the connection has been lost.

**On my staging environment**, it's a little bit more complicated:

```
[device] <==> [switch] <==> [internet] <==> [IIS reverse proxy] <==> [asp.net core app(kestrel)]
```

In that case it's just weird: when I disconnect the websocket client device, I still get PONGs from the IIS...

I did captures with wireshark to confirm that. **So my question is/are: who is sending PONGs on the behalf of the client?** Is it the reverse proxy (IIS in my case)? Is that normal? How can avoid that? Is it something in the IIS configuration?

Edit: I just tested it with nginx instead of IIS on a linux server, and I get the same behavior. So I must have missed something!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the we can't rely on websocket ping/pong to garantee a correct line check, as [they (ping) may not be sent](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2464#issuecomment-484193415) down to client. Depending to the infrastructure, they [may be intercepted by a proxy](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2464#issuecomment-484206910) or other link(s) in the chain.

[Ping/pong becomes unrelevant](https://mcguirev10.com/2019/08/18/minimal-full-feature-kestrel-websocket-server.html#websocket-ping-pong) for connection checking in such a configuration.

It's just disapointing that the [RFC is not more constraining](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.2) about that!

Furthermore, there is some indication in [asp.net core's websocket documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.0#handle-client-disconnects) about how to handle a proper connection check.